# Warum gibt es keine traditionell deutschen* Vornamen, die mit "Sch" beginnen?

Tags: person-names

Mir ist spontan kein Vorname, der mit `sch` beginnt und nicht vom Englischen eingedeutscht wurde, eingefallen. Ich habe also gesucht und nur relativ exotische Namen, wie folgt, gefunden:

- Schwanhilde
- Schorsch (ist ja nur (?) eine Kurzform)
- Schwerthelm
- Schwiedhard

Gibt es dafür eine gute Erklärung oder ist das einfach Zufall?

`*` Edit: "traditionell deutsch" ist vielleicht etwas ungenau oder zu subjektiv. Ich meine damit Vornamen, die man heute sowohl an jeder x-beliebigen Schule/KiTa, wie auch in irgendwelchen Altersheimen findet. Das schließt z.B. hoffentlich sowas wie "Jimmy Blue" aus. Klar, Vornamen unterliegen geschmacklichen Vorlieben. Aber ich kann mir vorstellen, dass z.B. in Japan oder Lesotho es durchaus möglich ist, Vornamen zu finden die mit einem Laut anfangen, den wir in Deutsch mit `Sch` aufschreiben.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Namen verhalten sich grundsätzlich wie alle anderen Wörter, was die Etymologie betrifft. »Traditionell deutsche Vornamen« lassen sich einteilen in:

- von Germanischen Vorläufern abgeleitete Namen
- aus klassischen (altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch) oder biblischen (hebräisch) Namen abgeleitete Namen

Ich denke, die Frage möchte ersteres diskutieren.

Zuerst muss die Frage nach der Herkunft des *Sch* geklärt werden. Der entsprechende Zischlaut findet sich nicht im rekonstruierten [Urgermanischen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urgermanische_Sprache) und auch das [Gotische](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotische_Sprache), die älteste germanische Sprache, von der wir schriftliche Belege haben, kennt ihn nicht. Er entstand irgendwo zwischen dem Althochdeutschen (das *sc* noch als /sk/ aussprache, wie heute noch im Englischen oder in skandinavischen Sprachen häufig üblich) und dem Neuhochdeutschen. Ursprünglich wahrscheinlich als Lautwandel aus /sk/ über /sx/ wobei das Schriftbild von *sc* zu *sch* wurde und dort verharrte. Außerdem wurden die Kombinationen *s* + Konsonant (außer *st* und *sp*) und *rs* wohl sehr früh als *sch*-Laute ausgesprochen, weswegen entsprechende Wörter (*Schwein, Schlag, schmecken, Schnecke, harsch*) bald auch mit *sch* geschrieben wurden. *St* und *sp* folgten später, wobei die niederdeutschen Dialekte den Lautwandel nicht völlig oder verzögert mitgemacht haben; dieser Lautwandel wurde nicht in der Rechtschreibung festgehalten. (Dort, wo im Auslaut *rs* auf *t* trifft, herrscht in oberdeutschen Dialekten *rscht* vor, während in niederdeutschen eher /rst/ gesprochen wird – vgl. *Wurscht*.)

Da *S* der [zweithäufigste Anfangsbuchstabe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchstabenh%C3%A4ufigkeit#Anfangsbuchstaben) (10,8 %) in deutschen Texten ist, könnte man argumentieren, dass es genügend germanische Namen mit *S* gäbe, die sich etymologisch zu *sch* entwickelt haben.

An dieser Stelle muss man aber beachten, wie germanische Namen in der Regel gebildet wurden: Üblicherweise wurden [zwei Bestandteile zusammengefügt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorname#Vorname/Rufname), wobei ursprünglich die inhaltliche Bedeutung wichtig war, zu späterer Zeit nurmehr Wohlklang. Schaut man sich diese Bestandteile an, stellt man fest, dass es insgesamt relativ wenige waren: Auf der [Liste deutscher Vornamen germanischer Herkunft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Vornamen_germanischer_Herkunft) finde ich gerade 65 Gruppen mit gemeinsamen Erstbestandteilen. Darunter fallen *Sieg-* und *Stein-* mit *S* als Anfangsbuchstabe. Statistisch gesehen würde man 2,5 pro Buchstabe erwarten, wenn die Buchstaben gleich verteilt wären. Streicht man *C, Q, X, Y, Z* – die überwiegend keine germanischen Anlaute repräsentieren – und *V* – das entweder *F* oder *W* entspricht – bleiben 20, womit statistisch gesehen jeder Buchstabe 3,25 Gruppen haben sollte. In beiden Fällen ist *S* mit zwei solchen Gruppen zwar statistisch leicht unterrepräsentiert aber doch im Rahmen zufälliger Verteilungen.

Was den zweiten Spiegelstrich betrifft: Das Hebräische kannte zwar einen /ʃ/-Anlaut, Griechisch und Latein aber nicht. Da Hebräische Namen in der Regel über Griechisch oder Latein zu uns kamen (dank der Bibelübersetzungen), verloren sie auf diesem Weg ihr /ʃ/ – so wurde zum Beispiel aus [*Schlomo* *Salomon*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schelomo) oder aus Schmuel Samuel. Einige Vornamen, wie zum Beispiel *Stefan* aus dem Griechischen, unterlagen zwar dem oben erwähnten Lautwandel (daher auf Deutsch /ʃtefan/ während er zum Beispiel auf Englisch /stefan/ ausgesprochen würde), werden aber heutzutage nicht mit *Sch* geschrieben. Daher ist auch diese Herleitungsquelle wenig ergiebig.

Zusammengefasst lässt sich sagen:
Es gibt keinen lautlichen Grund, warum diese Vornamen ausgeschlossen sein sollten – siehe *Stefan* oder der Spitzname *Schorsch*. Alte germanischen Namen hatten jedoch nur äußerst selten die Lautkombination, die sich zu /ʃ/ entwickeln würde. Latein und Altgriechisch kannten /ʃ/ gar nicht, es war aber möglich, dass sich Namen aus diesen Sprachen zufällig zu /ʃ/ entwickelten – allerdings ist *Stefan* der bekannteste Kandidat. Aus dem Hebräischen könnte man Namen mit *Sch* vermuten, da /ʃ/ bekannt war, sie wurden aber in der Regel unter /ʃ/-Verlust über das Griechische oder Lateinische übernommen.