# Grammatikalische Regeln beim Erstellen von Spiegelstrichlisten

Tags: sentence-structure

Satzzeichen in Aufzählungen sind sehr unterschiedlich. Häufig beginnen sie groß, in jedem Fall wenn es ganze Sätze sind, oft auch klein, wenn es sich wie eine Wortgruppe liest. Habe schon von Subjekt freien Sätzen gehört, die weder im Imperativ noch mit unsichtbarem "es" formuliert sind. Zum Beispiel folgende [Aufzählung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61390/warum-gibt-es-keine-traditionell-deutschen-vornamen-die-mit-sch-beginnen/61439#61439) ließe sich doch auf verschiedene Arten schreiben. Welche davon sind nicht korrekt und warum?

1.

> Traditionell deutsche Vornamen lassen sich einteilen in:
>
> - von Germanischen Vorläufern abgeleitete Namen
> - aus klassischen (altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch) oder biblischen (hebräisch) Namen abgeleitete Namen

2. 

> Traditionell deutsche Vornamen lassen sich einteilen in:
>
> - Von Germanischen Vorläufern abgeleitete Namen
> - Aus klassischen (altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch) oder biblischen (hebräisch) Namen abgeleitete Namen

3. 

> Traditionell deutsche Vornamen lassen sich einteilen in:
>
> - von Germanischen Vorläufern abgeleitete Namen,
> - aus klassischen (altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch),
> - oder biblischen (hebräisch) Namen abgeleitete Namen.

4. 

> Traditionell deutsche Vornamen lassen sich einteilen in:
>
> - Von Germanischen Vorläufern abgeleitete Namen.
> - Aus klassischen (altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch) oder biblischen (hebräisch) Namen abgeleitete Namen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt durchaus ein paar Regeln zur Gestaltung von Aufzählungen - schauen wir einmal in die Regeln des Rechtschreibrats:

1. §67E3: Man setzt keinen Punkt am Ende einer kolumnenartigen Aufzählung ohne schließende Satzzeichen
   (bedeutet: läßt man die Kommas weg, läßt man auch den Punkt am Ende weg)
2. §71E2: Das Komma (und gegebenenfalls der Schlusspunkt) kann in kolumnenartigen Aufzählungen fehlen, zum Beispiel:

   *Unser Sonderangebot:*

   – *Äpfel*

   – *Birnen*

   – *Orangen*

   (bedeutet: das Komma zwischen Spiegelstrichen darf entfallen, dann muß aber nach (1) auch der Punkt am Ende weg)

Sind die Spiegelstriche jedoch ganze Sätze oder Satzgruppen, kann man das im Sinne der Regeln wohl nicht mehr als "kolumnenartige Aufzählung" werten. Dann würde ich Satzzeichen so setzen wie im "normalen" Text (also mit Großschreibung am Anfang und Punkt am Ende).

Demnach ist dein Beispiele (4) auf jeden Fall falsch, (3) ist erlaubt.

Was die Großschreibung am Spiegelstrich-Anfang angeht, sagen §54/5 und /6, dass:

> Gliederungsangaben wie Ziffern, Paragrafen, Buchstaben gehören nicht zum nachfolgenden Ganzsatz; entsprechend schreibt man das folgende Wort groß. Dies gilt auch für Überschriften, Werktitel und dergleichen.

aber:

Diese Regel beginnt mit "Das erste Wort eines Ganzsatzes schreibt man groß"-Ich deute das so, dass, wenn der Inhalt des Spiegelstrichs ein Ganzsatz ist, groß geschrieben, ansonsten klein geschrieben wird. In deinen Beispielen findet sich kein *Satz* im Spiegelstrich, deswegen würde ich nur deine Beispiele (1) und (3) für richtig halten, (1) halte ich (zumindestens bei kurzem Inhalt der Spiegelstriche wie in deinen Beispielen) für praktikabler.

Answer (score 4):

In der Schule habe ich vor langer Zeit noch gelernt, dass man in dem Fall Satzzeichen einfach so setzt, als seien die Spiegelstriche und Zeilenumbrüche  nicht vorhanden und die ganze Aufzählung ein durchgehender Text. Diese Regel führt natürlich zu verschiedenen Möglichkeiten, abhängig vom Satzzusammenhang, in dem die Teile stehen, und z.B. davon, ob man einen Doppelpunkt setzen möchte, ob man Strichpunkte benutzen möchte, u.ä.

In der Duden-Grammatik finde ich zu dem Thema allerdings nichts.

Die Version 1 bis 4 aus der Frage verstoßen alle an irgendeiner Stelle gegen diese Regel. Möglich wäre zum Beispiel:

> Traditionell deutsche Vornamen lassen sich einteilen in *(<- optional Doppelpunkt)*
>
> - von germanischen Vorläufern abgeleitete Namen, *(<- Komma)*
> - aus klassischen (altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch) *(<- kein Komma)*
> - oder biblischen (hebräisch) Namen abgeleitete Namen.

Man kommt hier m.E. aber auch in einen Bereich, in dem man sich überlegen kann, wie sinnvoll es überhaupt ist, noch Regeln aufstellen zu wollen. Gegen 25 Jahre chaotische Powerpoint-Praxis, in der sich nur sehr wenige Nutzer je an irgendwelche Regeln gehalten haben und jeder nach persönlichem Geschmack vorgegangen ist, kommt kein schriftliches Regelwerk an.

Comment: Lässt sich die Liste auch durch Passivsätze  gliedern wie `... - Ableitung von Namen aus germanischen Vorläufern. - Ableitung von Namen aus klassischen oder biblischen Namen.`

Comment: M.E. sollte der Text nach jedem Spiegelstrich für sich alleine lesbar sein. Beim zweiten würde ich daher am Ende "Namen" ergänzen.  Inhaltlich sollte man sich gut überlegen, wie viele Namensgruppen man differenzieren möchte: *Zwei* (germanisch /  altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch, hebräisch) oder *drei* (germanisch /  altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch / hebräisch). Daraus ergibt sich dann die Struktur der Spiegelstriche.

Comment: @PaulFrost, abgesehen davon, dass sich der 2u3 Stichpunkt zusammenführen lässt. Was bedeutet bei dir "... für sich alleine lesbar... " ? Wären es: Sätze, Wortgruppen ohne Komma oder Nebensätze mit Komma getrennt und am Ende der Punkt?

Answer (score 0):

Diese Antwort ist ein erweiterter Kommentar zu HalvarFs Antwort.

M.E. sollte der Text nach jedem Spiegelstrich für sich alleine lesbar sein. Wenn man die Varianten 2. und 4. wegen Großschreibung von "Von" und "Aus" zurecht ausschließt, ist das nur bei Variante 1. der Fall.

Bei Variante 3 ist

- von germanischen Vorläufern abgeleitete Namen

für sich alleine lesbar, nicht aber

- aus klassischen (altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch)

Verständlichkeit wird erst beim Lesen des folgenden Spiegelstrichs erreicht. Ich würde also am Ende "Namen abgeleitete Namen" ergänzen.

Beim dritten Spiegelstrich würde ich das "oder" weglassen, weil die Spiegelstriche ja gerade Alternativen darstellen sollen und daher das "oder" implizit enthalten.

Also:

> Traditionell deutsche Vornamen lassen sich einteilen in
>
> - von germanischen Vorläufern abgeleitete Namen,
> - aus klassischen (altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch) Namen abgeleitete Namen,
> - aus biblischen (hebräisch) Namen abgeleitete Namen.

Außerdem könnte man in allen drei Spiegelstrichen einheitlich "von" oder "aus" verwenden.

Eine weitere Variante ist

> Traditionell deutsche Vornamen lassen sich einteilen in Namen mit Ableitung aus
>
> - germanischen Vorläufern,
> - klassischen (altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch) Namen,
> - biblischen (hebräisch) Namen.

Inhaltlich sollte man sich gut überlegen, wie viele Namensgruppen man differenzieren möchte:

**Zwei** ( 1.germanisch - 2.  altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch, hebräisch) oder **drei** (1. germanisch - 2. altgriechisch, römisch/lateinisch - 3. hebräisch). Daraus ergibt sich dann die Struktur der Spiegelstriche.